# why the output is last string from user?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int in,i,j;
    char *arr[100],str[14];
    scanf("%d",&in);
    i=0;
    while(i<in)
    {
        scanf("%s",str);
        arr[i]=str;
      //  printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    while(i<in)
    {
      printf("%s\n",arr[i++]);

    }
  return 0;

}
```

/* in this code i had take input strings from user and wants to print it back but it is printing the last string input by the user .WHY?? */

Comment: You need to allocate memory for each string `arr[i]` and need to use `strcpy` copy string.

Comment: When you are all done, you will find that you input the number of strings and your program skips over the `str` entry every other time. This is because the `newline` (from pressing `[enter]` after you enter data) remains in the input buffer (`stdin`) and is taken as `str` by `scanf`. You need to adjust your `scanf` format string to ignore (and consume) any `newline` that remains in `stdin` (and discard) the `newline` created when you press `[enter]`. Like: `scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",str);`

Answer (score 2):

You are storing every string in the same place, overwriting the previous string each time.  Don't do that.  `str` is a buffer, and all of the pointers in the array `arr` are pointing at it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `arr[i]=str;` statement.

`str` is a statically allocated array, and **all** the `arr[i]` are storing the base address of it.

As the value of `str` get overwritten in every call to `scanf()`,  in your case, only the last value stored in `str` will be printed by accessing **any**  `arr[i]`.

What you need to do

1. Allocate memory [dynamically](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to `arr[100]`.
2. use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the user input from `str` to `arr[i]`

Note: Don't forget to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the allocated memory at last.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are assigning the memory address to the array of pointer. So the address of the 
array will not be changed. Every array of pointer is pointing to the same address.

When the new value is get then it will place that value in array at same address position.

So the all values are remaining same. So avoid this you can make the str to pointer. And allocate the memory to that pointer dynamically.

`char *str;`Make the allocation in while loop
`str=malloc(MAX);`

```
while(i<in)
{ str=malloc(100);//change
    scanf("%s",str);
    arr[i]=str;
  //  printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    i++;
}
```

100 is an example. you can use your needed value.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in your loop.

```
while(i<in)
{
    scanf("%s",str);
    arr[i]=malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str));
    strcpy(arr[i],str);
  //  printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    i++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you keep on using the same `char[] str` for all strings.

Instead, you probably want to allocate a new memory block for each string. Don't forget to free them again after use.

You can check that in the loop

```
while(i<in)
{
  printf("%p\t%s\n",arr[i],arr[i]);
  i++;
}
```

and you see that not only the string is the same, but its address as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for each string `arr[i]` and then use `strcpy` for copy string.

Add some code like below in your loop.

```
arr[i]=malloc(strlen(str)+1);
strcpy(arr[i],str);
```

Also never forgot to free memory for above allocation at the end of program.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other responses, there are a few alternative ways to approach reading string input that you can use to simplify the what you need to keep track of in the program. As others suggested, instead of declaring `arr` as `char *arr[100]`, go ahead and declare it as a `pointer-to-pointer-to-char`.

```
char **arr = NULL;
```

This allows you to allocate an array of character pointers. You can choose to allocate with `malloc` or you can choose to allocate and initialize all pointers to `zero/NULL` simply by using `calloc` instead.

```
arr = calloc (100, sizeof *arr);
```

By using `calloc`, this allows later iteration over only those pointers that contain strings. This further eliminates having to ask for the number of strings to enter (or keep track of how many were entered).

After you have allocated your pointers, you need to allocate space to hold each string. While there is nothing wrong with another call to `malloc` (or `calloc`) and then a call to `strcpy` (or `strncpy`), you can do both at once with the function `strdup` provided in `string.h`. The only thing to be aware of with `strdup` is that it is allocating memory for you. Therefore, you are responsible for freeing that memory when no longer needed.

Putting the pieces together, as well as the information from the comment regarding your `scanf` string, you can implement your string collection as follows. **Note** You simply enter as many strings as you like (up to the 100 pointers initially allocated), then press `[enter]` on a blank line when you are done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    int i = 0;                              /* always initialize your variables */
    char **arr = NULL;
    char str[14] = { 0 };

    arr = calloc (100, sizeof *arr);        /* create 100 pointers to char*     */

    printf ("\nEnter strings ( [enter] alone when done )\n\n");

    while (printf (" input: ") && scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", str) >= 1)
        arr[i++] = strdup (str);            /* strdup allocates and copies  */

    printf ("\nThe strings entered were:\n\n");
    i = 0;                                  /* print the array              */
    while (arr[i]) {
        printf (" arr[%2d]: %s\n", i, arr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;                                  /* free memory allocated        */
    while (arr[i])
        free (arr[i++]);
    if (arr)
        free (arr);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/str_array

Enter strings ( [enter] alone when done )

 input: string 1
 input: string 2
 input: string 3
 input:

The strings entered were:

 arr[ 0]: string 1
 arr[ 1]: string 2
 arr[ 2]: string 3
```

There are many, many ways to approach this problem. Compare all the answers and add the different approaches to your collection. There are always places where one will have benefits over the other, and vice-versa. Note, in the above code you should check whether any allocation with `calloc`, `malloc`, or `strdup` succeeds and handle the error if it fails. You should also check when you get to the 99th sting entered and reallocate the number of pointers as needed. Those checks are omitted for clarity.

**valgrind memory useage summary**

Get in the habit of always verifying your memory usage with `valgrind`. It will point out any place where you have allocated memory that you have failed to free. While the memory in a short bit of code like this will be freed on `exit`, in longer code, failing to keep track of the memory you allocate can lead to significant amounts of memory in use by your program after it is no longer needed (memory leaks). A quick check with `valgrind` will disclose any problems or confirm all is well:

```
==28677== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28677==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28677==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 827 bytes allocated
==28677==
==28677== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==28677==
==28677== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28677== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.