# All the values are the same when I use dynamic allocation

Tags: c

I try to get words from user until he enters `0` and then print it. I want to dynamically allocate a size for the list after every word (by using struct):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct my_struct
{
    char** words;
    int length;
} my_struct;


int main(void)
{
    struct my_struct list = { 0,0 };
    list.words = (char**)malloc(0);
    int choice = 1, i = 0;
    char str[30];
    printf("Enter 0 to exit or any other number to continue: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice)
    {
        list.length += 1;
        list.words = (char**)realloc(list.words, sizeof(char*) * list.length);
        printf("Enter a word: ");
        getchar();
        fgets(str, 30, stdin);
        list.words[list.length - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
        list.words[list.length - 1] = str;
        printf("Enter 0 to exit or any other number to continue: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("Values:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", list.words[i]);
    }
    free(list.words);
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycAqJ.png)
Why does it happen?

Comment: You need to copy the string into the memory you allocate. You're just assigning a pointer and leaking memory right now.

Comment: You are reading every input into array `str`, and then assigning a pointer to `str` to your list element.  All the elements point to the same place.  Learn to use `strcpy()` instead of `=` to copy strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why the output is last string from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27540759/why-the-output-is-last-string-from-user)

Comment: If you change the lines: `list.words[list.length - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 30);
list.words[list.length - 1] = str;` into `list.words[list.length -1]=strdup(str);` you will be more pleased.  You are allocating memory and throwing it away with the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the string incorrectly:

```
list.words[list.length - 1] = str;
```

this just assigns the `list.words` pointer to `str` and `str` gets overwritten by the latest word the user inputs.  You need to

```
strcpy(list.words[list.length - 1], str);
```

Comment: What error?  Perhaps `strcpy undefined`?  If so then #include <string.h>

Comment: I know, still got error. I added the line list.words[list.length -1]=strdup(str); and now it works

Comment: I can't help you if you don't tell me what the error is.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't give details (in c at least). "The program stopped working"